# While loop printing Input Values along with the correct output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n ;
    
    while(n != ' '){
     
        scanf("%d",&n);
        
        if( n/2 + n/3 + n/4 > n){
            printf("%d\n", n/2 + n/3 + n/4);
        }else{
            printf("%d\n",n);
        }       
    
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
12

2
13
2
```

Why does 12 and 2 get printed?

Comment: To begin with you use `n` *uninitialized*. Secondly, since you read it as integers, it will never be equal to the character `' '`. ***Always*** check what [`scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If the user enters 32 it will be `n = ' '`. ;)

Comment: Please Can you suggest the changes  for the issue of the input getting printed ? I cant think of how to resolve it . And in consideration to '  ' @Some programmer dude , i wanted to stop the scan when the input  provided by the user is stopped.

Comment: Do e.g. `while (scanf(...) == 1)` instead. And press the EOF key sequence on your system (`Ctrl-Z` on Windows, or `Ctrl-D` on Linux or macOS).

Comment: @Pinalen It's hard to suggest changes, because it's very unclear what you want to do.

Comment: https://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/ i was solving this

Answer (score 0):

Make while loop condition as. And not scan inside the while loop.

```
while((scanf("%d",&n)) != EOF)
```

Comment: This will not catch invalid input when `scanf` returns `0`. Better compare against `1` instead.

Comment: I had told according the problem given in comment. https://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/

Comment: Thanks ! All of you